# parse a string and print all database values to a textview

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am trying to colour text for my android app depending on a value entered into the `SQLite` database. I have set up 3 `textviews` and have different text colours for all of these.

The code looks like this

```
String arr[] = data.split("..\n\n");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("arr["+i+"] = " + arr[i].trim());

    if(arr[i].contains("High Severity"))
    {
       // String highArr = arr[i];
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView.setText(highArr+"\n");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if(arr[i].contains("Low Severity"))
    {
        textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView3.setText(arr[i]+"\n");
        textView3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(arr[i].contains("Medium Severity"))
    {
        textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView2.setText(arr[i]+"\n");
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 136, 0));
    }

}
```

I have parsed the string which has all the values for my database table, but when I try my for loop it only prints out the latest entered values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be that your arr[] is only got one entry in it. You should use the debugger to see how many times your loop actually runs and what the actual lenght of the array is.

EDIT:

I just realized that you only have three textviews. Of course the textview is displaying the last one because each time your calling the settext method its reseting the text. There are a few ways to do what you are trying but Im not sure how your app is set up. You should try dynamically creating the textview, setting the text to it, then adding that textview to a linearlayout or relativelayout that you have set up. Or you could do this inside of a listview using a custom implementation of a baseadapter or any of the other adapters depending on your needs.

Comment: from logcat I have seen that the arr[] does hold all the values of my database but only the most recent gets printed to the screen... The logcat shows values up to [13]

Comment: try setting the string value at arr[i] to a temp variable so you can debug and see its real value. It could be your comparing to a value that you dont really have in there.

Comment: Thanks so much I'll start on the listview now!

Answer (score 0):

I would change my code like this:

```
String arr[] = data.split("..\n\n");
String Hseverity = "", Mseverity = "", Lseverity = "";
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("arr["+i+"] = " + arr[i].trim());

    if(arr[i].contains("High Severity"))
    {
       // String highArr = arr[i];
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Hseverity += arr[i] +"\n";
        textView.setText(Hseverity);//do this to save each High Severity entry
        //same for the other severity levels
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if(arr[i].contains("Low Severity"))
    {
        textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Lseverity += arr[i]+"\n";
        textView3.setText(Lseverity);
        textView3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(arr[i].contains("Medium Severity"))
    {
        textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Mseverity += arr[i] + "\n";
        textView2.setText(Mseverity);
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 136, 0));
    }

}
```